# Request a non-blocking server AsyncTask Android Studio?

Tags: android, mysql, android-studio, android-fragments

I'm developing my first robust App in Android Studio is an application that communicates with a remote database, for this I am using the AsyncTask class, also made the request in a separate thread, all this I have already done, the question is that I am using a DrawerLayout and every time a menu item is selected, this gets stuck while the data request to the server is done, as I do to make such request is made the one you see DrawerLayout be hidden.

This is how I am running the AsyncTask class.

```
   BD = new TaskExecuteHttpHandler(service, parametros, CONTEXTO);

    String resultado="";
    try {
        resultado = BD.execute().get();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I appreciate the help.